# MM/dd/yyyy datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I am inputting 2 date values in order to filter out from SQL query.

```
 EXEC [Report].[usp_EmployeeReport_Detail] '01-01-2017','31-08-2019'
```

I am inputting the date as `MM/dd/yyyy` and the 
`WHERE` clause contains

```
(j.StartDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate)
```

I m getting the below error when executing the query.

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I tried to convert the datetime result using the below way as well.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,01-31-2017,101)
```

This returns `1894-05-25 00:00:00.000` as the response. How its possible?

Comment: Because `1` minus `31` is `-30` and further subtracting 2017 from that number gives us `-2047`. 25th May 1894 is (I would strongly guess) 2047 days before SQL Server's 0 date, 1900-01-01. If you're passing this value from some other program, please investigate whether there are better language bindings than passing it to SQL Server as a string (or even, in your final example, not even treating it as a  string)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818498/mm-dd-yyyy-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of-range-value/51818856#comment90590977_51818498) has said,`01-31-2017` using the Numerical expression, which evaluates to `-2047`.

`-2047` means the day minus `2047` days from `1900-01-01`, so result of date will be `1894-05-25 00:00:00.000`.

So your query `SELECT CONVERT(datetime,01-31-2017,101)` same as `SELECT CONVERT(datetime,-2047,101)`

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/29438)

---

You can use the ANSI compliant format `YYYYMMDD`

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'20170131',101);
```

instead of

`DD-MM-YYYY` `01-31-2017`.

Or just add `'` to contain the date `'01-31-2017'` like [@fa06](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818523/5176071) answered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: u've missed the quote in date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'01-31-2017',101)
```

Answer (score 0):

try below way

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),1 )

it returns 08/13/18
```

in your case you missed the quote as a result output that type shown